# How to establish a default gateway in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: default, gateway

I am trying to get a server running on Ubuntu 14.04 to work with an attached router with a fixed LAN address of 192.168.1.1. The server manufacturer said I needed to setup a default route. I found a post via Google that said the procedure with 14.04 from the command line is:

`ip add default via (router LAN address) dev eth0`.

Is this correct and do I need to undo to it if he doesn't work? If so, how?

I don't know what terms like "eth0" mean and have essentially no experience working with command lines other than DOS many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check your current automatic settings with `ifconfig`. If the gateway hasn't been automatically set, you can do it manually by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`. Something like;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```